# Created a New Zend Controller but can't access when Specified in Layout?

Tags: zend-framework

I created a New Controller with:

```
zf create controller email
```

but the resulting files weren't put in `application/modules`, they were put in `application/`...

Anyway I moved the controller and view files into the correct directory

then I used:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array(), 'email');?>">EMAIL</a>
```

After I refresh the page it gives a `internal Error 500`

Don't Really know what's cutting -> it's `Zend Version: 1.12.1`

Comment: If it's application error then most likely an exception was thrown. Can you please provide us with the exception message?

Answer (score 1):

$this->url() view helper works by matching the parameters given and the route name, to create a URI.

In order for your code to work, you have to:

1 - In your router file, specify the route, for example:

```
    $router->addRoute(
        'email', 
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('([\w\d\.\_]+)@([\w\d\.]+)([\s]*)',
            array(
                'module' => 'default',
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            array(
                1 => 'username',
                2 => 'host'
            ),
            '%s@%s'
        )
    );
```

The first param for addRoute is the name of the route and that's what you use as the second parameter for `$this->url()`. The second parameter is a Router adapter. There are many different adapters (check the manual), this one is the regex adapter.

First param - the regex string for checking the uri. You will want to modify this to a more e-mail wise regex, but for now this should be enough.

The second param is your defaults.

The third - variables. For each group in your regex you should specify a name, so the group before the @ will become `1 => 'username'` and after - `2 => 'host'`.

And finally the fourth param - very important - the reversed route. This one is actually the one Zend uses to glue the pieces. You create it by changing each group to a "symbol", so the whole thing becomes `"%s@%s"` - you'll have to read some articles on how to create those - I just go with %d for digits only, %w for letters only and %s for mixed, didn't ever need anything more.

2 - After you setup the router, go back to your view file and modify the function so it looks like this:

```
    $this->url(array('username' => 'test', 'host' => 'test.com'), 'email');
```

Your resulting html should look like this:

```
<a href="test@test.com">EMAIL</a>
```

3 - Turn on error_reporting, either in your server configuration or the zend application ini file. You'll have a much greater insight into what's actually malfunctioning.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `configs/application.ini` file to configure and bootstrap:

So adding the following lines to the file works!

```
resources.router.routes.email.route = /email
resources.router.routes.email.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.email.defaults.controller = email
resources.router.routes.email.defaults.action = index
```

So the routes apparently need to be explicitly declared and are not handled by `zf tool`